# Why can't I save changes to my Colab Notebook from another device?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

So, I work on multiple devices and I Colab to work with my projects. When I create a notebook file on my PC, then try to make changes to that notebook, it says I'm not authorised to make changes to this file, while I use the same account for my Google Drive(where colab notebooks are uploaded), Colaboratory and yet I'm not able to save changes to my own notebook

I always made a copy of those notebooks to save changes from my phone, but that feels like an unnecessary hassle

Comment: So you create a notebook on your PC and then you try to open it from an other device and it doesn't work?

Comment: No. It does work. The file opens, I'm able to edit and run the file, but I'm unable to save the changes. The reason it shows is that I'm not permitted to make changes to the file, while I am the owner

Comment: There might be a problem with your account; you should contact the support of Google Colab

Comment: I'll surely try that. The reason I asked first was, if others are facing the same, then it might be a problem already in fixation process. Thanks for your response